Two different embeddings $ \mathbb R \to \mathbb C $ over $ \mathbb R $?
How to find all embeddings $ \mathbb R \to \mathbb C $ over $ \mathbb R $? I have found only trivial one
$$ x \mapsto x + 0i, $$
but from theory it is known that $ [\mathbb C : \mathbb R]_s = \#\{\mathbb R \xrightarrow{f} \mathbb C \mid f|_{\mathbb R} = id\} = 2 $, because in zero characteristic every extension is separable and separability implies $ [\mathbb C : \mathbb R]_s = [\mathbb C : \mathbb R] $.
However it is clear remaining morphism shouldn't be $ \mathbb R $-linear, because otherwise ($ \mathbb R \xrightarrow{f} \mathbb C $) $ f(x) = x f(1) $ and morphism property $ f(xy) = f(x) f(y) $ implies $ f(1)^2 = f(1) $, but the one with $ f(1) = -1 $ is not fitting.

Do you mean $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{R}$?

@ljfirth no, I want to describe field morphisms $ \mathbb R \to \mathbb C $ that extends identity on $ \mathbb R $

What is your definition of field morphism?

There is none, by definition. If you "extend the identity on $\mathbb{R}$" to $\mathbb{R}$, you get... the identity.

The separable degree counts morphisms $\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ that fix $\mathbb R$. Then you get conjugation as the second map.

@CaptainLama sorry, got brain lag. That's the right answer

@anankElpis Please copy your comment as answer, so the OP can choose it and the question can be marked Answered.

For a field extension $K\subset L$, the separable degree is usually defined as $$[L:K]_s:=|\operatorname{Hom}_K(L,\overline K)|,$$ i.e. the $K$-linear field morphisms from $L$ to an algebraic closure of $K$. Thus in this case we have to count $\mathbb R$-linear maps $\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$, and we find two of them: the identity and complex conjugation. These are the only ones, since we need $f(i)^2=-1$, so $f(i)=\pm i$. Hence $[\mathbb C:\mathbb R]_s=2$, which agrees with the fact that $[\mathbb C:\mathbb R]_s=[\mathbb C:\mathbb R]$.

Why was my answer downvoted? Is there something wrong or to be improved?

I have chosen and up voted your answer. Thank you for correcting my misconception about separable degree
